# How to fix Error #1000: The system is out of memory while using ForcibleLoader.as in Adobe Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, loader

Adobe Air in ActinoScript3 ForcibleLoader.as
Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.

https://gist.github.com/nsdevaraj/409902

```
package
{
        import flash.display.Loader;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.URLStream;
        import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
        import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
        import flash.system.LoaderContext;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;
        import flash.utils.Endian;
        import flash.errors.EOFError;
       
        /**
         * Loads a SWF file as version 9 format forcibly even if version is under 9.
         *
         * Usage:
         * <pre>
         * var loader:Loader = Loader(addChild(new Loader()));
         * var fLoader:ForcibleLoader = new ForcibleLoader(loader);
         * fLoader.load(new URLRequest('swf7.swf'));
         * </pre>
         *
         * @author yossy:beinteractive
         * @see http://www.be-interactive.org/?itemid=250
         * @see http://fladdict.net/blog/2007/05/avm2avm1swf.html
         */
        public class ForcibleLoader
        {
                public function ForcibleLoader(loader:Loader)
                {
                        this.loader = loader;
                       
                        _stream = new URLStream();
                        _stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                        _stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
                        _stream.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
                }
               
                private var _loader:Loader;
                private var _stream:URLStream;
                private var _lc :LoaderContext;
               
                public function get loader():Loader
                {
                        return _loader;
                }
               
                public function set loader(value:Loader):void
                {
                        _loader = value;
                }
               
                public function load(request:URLRequest):void
                {
                        _stream.load(request);
                }

                public function set lc(value):void{
                        _lc=value;
                }
                public function get lc():LoaderContext{
                        return _lc;
                }
               
                private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
                {
                        var inputBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                        _stream.readBytes(inputBytes);
                        _stream.close();
                        inputBytes.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
                       
                        if (isCompressed(inputBytes)) {
                                uncompress(inputBytes); ////////////////// ERROR
                        }
                       
                        var version:uint = uint(inputBytes[3]);
                       
                        if (version < 9) {
                                updateVersion(inputBytes, 9);
                        }
                        if (version > 7) {
                                flagSWF9Bit(inputBytes);
                        }
                        else {
                                insertFileAttributesTag(inputBytes);
                        }
                       
                        loader.loadBytes(inputBytes, lc);
                }
               
                private function isCompressed(bytes:ByteArray):Boolean
                {
                        return bytes[0] == 0x43;
                }
               
                private function uncompress(bytes:ByteArray):void
                {
                        var cBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                        cBytes.writeBytes(bytes, 8);
                        bytes.length = 8;
                        bytes.position = 8;
                        cBytes.uncompress(); ////////////////// ERROR
                        bytes.writeBytes(cBytes);
                        bytes[0] = 0x46;
                        cBytes.length = 0;
                }
               
                private function getBodyPosition(bytes:ByteArray):uint
                {
                        var result:uint = 0;
                       
                        result += 3; // FWS/CWS
                        result += 1; // version(byte)
                        result += 4; // length(32bit-uint)
                       
                        var rectNBits:uint = bytes[result] >>> 3;
                        result += (5 + rectNBits * 4) / 8; // stage(rect)
                       
                        result += 2;
                       
                        result += 1; // frameRate(byte)
                        result += 2; // totalFrames(16bit-uint)
                       
                        return result;
                }
               
                private function findFileAttributesPosition(offset:uint, bytes:ByteArray):int
                {
                        bytes.position = offset;
                       
                        try {
                                for (;;) {
                                        var byte:uint = bytes.readShort();
                                        var tag:uint = byte >>> 6;
                                        if (tag == 69) {
                                                return bytes.position - 2;
                                        }
                                        var length:uint = byte & 0x3f;
                                        if (length == 0x3f) {
                                                length = bytes.readInt();
                                        }
                                        bytes.position += length;
                                }
                        }
                        catch (e:EOFError) {
                        }
                       
                        return -1;
                }
               
                private function flagSWF9Bit(bytes:ByteArray):void
                {
                        var pos:int = findFileAttributesPosition(getBodyPosition(bytes), bytes);
                        if (pos != -1) {
                                bytes[pos + 2] |= 0x08;
                        }
                        else {
                                insertFileAttributesTag(bytes);
                        }
                }
               
                private function insertFileAttributesTag(bytes:ByteArray):void
                {
                        var pos:uint = getBodyPosition(bytes);
                        var afterBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                        afterBytes.writeBytes(bytes, pos);
                        bytes.length = pos;
                        bytes.position = pos;
                        bytes.writeByte(0x44);
                        bytes.writeByte(0x11);
                        bytes.writeByte(0x08);
                        bytes.writeByte(0x00);
                        bytes.writeByte(0x00);
                        bytes.writeByte(0x00);
                        bytes.writeBytes(afterBytes);
                        afterBytes.length = 0;
                }
               
                private function updateVersion(bytes:ByteArray, version:uint):void
                {
                        bytes[3] = version;
                }
               
                private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
                {
                        loader.contentLoaderInfo.dispatchEvent(event.clone());
                }
               
                private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
                {
                        loader.contentLoaderInfo.dispatchEvent(event.clone());
                }
        }
}
```

Creating an AVM1Movie Type swf player in Adobe AIR using the "ForcibleLoader" class in the above path.
The loader for Action Script 2.0 version of the swf file works well, but when the file size is large, an error occurs in the ByteArray uncompress() method. It should be a problem)
Couldn't find similar error on google

Please let me know if there is a change in the large-capacity "uncompress()" method for "ByteArray" or if there is a site worth referencing.

Have a nice day then!

//-------------- error

```
Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/_uncompress()
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/uncompress()
    at ForcibleLoader/uncompress()[D:\sh\3. rNd\swfToMp4\03.screen recorder\swf\ForcibleLoader.as:104]
    at ForcibleLoader/completeHandler()[D:\sh\3. rNd\swfToMp4\03.screen recorder\swf\ForcibleLoader.as:75]
```

//-------------- Adobe Air ActionScrip`your text`t Code (LoaderContext part added)

```
var ldr :Loader=new Loader();
var lc :LoaderContext=new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
lc.allowCodeImport=true;
var url :URLRequest=new URLRequest("01_04.swf");

var fc :ForcibleLoader=new ForcibleLoader(ldr);
fc.lc=lc;


ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, com);
fc.load(url);

var mc :MovieClip;

function com(e :Event) :void
{
    trace( "load Complete" );
    var info :LoaderInfo=ldr.contentLoaderInfo;
    mc=info.content as MovieClip;
    addChild(mc);
    mc.buttonMode=true;
    mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e :MouseEvent) :void
{
    ( mc.isPlaying )?mc.stop():mc.play();
}
```

Comment: I cannot guarantee this will solve your problem, but here are some ideas. You use **URLStream** class, which is intended for handling a constant stream of data rather than for loading complete files, and after the loading is done you *double* the loaded data by copying it into a separate **ByteArray** then request another memory chunk to decompress it. I suggest using the basic **URLLoader** with its **dataFormat** property set to **URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY** to get its **data** property as **ByteArray** straight away.

Comment: Ok, I looked closer at your code. So, in your **uncompless** method you copy first 8 loaded bytes to some other **ByteArray** and then try to **uncompress** exactly these 8 bytes. It doesn't seem to make any sense. You don't and can't read and unpack an archive unless you have the whole thing. What is that you are trying to achieve there?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.


As I wrote above, I proceeded by using the "https://gist.github.com/nsdevaraj/409902" class to load AVM1Movie, but a problem occurred.

I'm trying various methods, but I lack experience in using ByteArray data.

Comment: * Thanks for the idea.
"Rather than loading the complete file, I use the URLStream class for handling a continuous stream of data, and after the load is complete, I double the loaded data by copying it to a separate ByteArray, then request another chunk of memory to decompress it."

==> Could you please elaborate a bit more on how you are requesting another chunk of memory to decompress after doubling the idea above?

Comment: * 8 byte question
- In the uncompless method, we copy the first loaded 8 bytes to another ByteArray and then try to unpack these 8 bytes exactly. It seems to make no sense.

==> Inexperience. I don't know why, but if the capacity is not large, the load is smooth.

Comment: Memory management. Unlike C/C++, you don't manage memory directly, but you need to keep in mind that Flash/AIR Player does that for you. When you load something, the code under the hood handles the incoming data and stores it somewhere. Then, you **_stream.readBytes(...)** copy the loaded data into the accessible structure = now you have both loaded data and copied data in the memory, thus effectively doubling it. When you **ByteArray.uncompress**, it does not overwrite the existing data immediately, but (under the hood) request additional memory for the uncompressed data first.

Comment: So, my advice remains: use **URLLoader** rather than **URLStream** and **ByteArray.uncompress()** the whole loaded data at once, rather than pieces of it. That, of course, if loading the movie directly via **Loader** doesn't work for you, somehow. Because, you know, you **can** load it with **Loader** and figure whatever you need to figure from the **Loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes** later.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I will try and write again.
Have a good day.